# How to program MVC Ajax with modal dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog, actionlink

I am newbie to Ajax MVC programming. I wanted to achieve something as outlined below:

1. I have a table of row data (Name, Location, and ReviewStatus) on the
   web page. The “ReviewStatus” column is updatable. It toggles between
   “Review” and “Reviewed”. The page is not refreshed only the data at
   the last column is changing.
2. I am doing Ajax.ActionLink to change the data.
3. Now I want to have the update conditional. I want to take user confirmation in a modal dialog before I change the “Review Status” based on location.

My problem is, because this is async, I cannot stop the execution to take the user input from modal dialog and then decide, if user wants to update or not.

This is a simplified version of an actual application where multiple users have the same dataset loaded in a browser and if one of the users have updated a row and a second user tries to update the same row it should ask for confirmation before override. I am checking if the row the second users is updating has changed since it was loaded in the browser.

I am probably doing it all wrong. This kind of problem may need to be solved differently. Anyhow, I am looking for suggestion/solution.

The following is the code that I was playing with. I added model, view, and controller code.
Also, I apologize,  if my questions and sample code is not framed properly. Someone please help me with edit; this is my first question to stack overflow.

Model Code: Restaurant.cs

```
[Serializable]
public class Restaurant
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string ReviewStatus { get; set; }

}
```

View : index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcAjaxApp.Models.Restaurant>

@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateonbegin(location)
    { 
        var b;
        var promise = verifyUpdate(location);
        promise.done(function (result) {
            //because of async execution does not stop for user input from dialog box. 
            b = confirmOverride(result);
        });
        promise.fail(function () {
            b =  false;
        });

        return b;
    }

    function confirmOverride(result)
    {
        if (result=== "Change") //return true so that status can be changed
        {
            return true;
        }
        else //return confirmation then decide what to do
        {
            $("#dialogText").text(result);
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Change": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        return true;
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function verifyUpdate(location )
    {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("IsUpdatedSinceLastLoad")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                location: location
            },
            async: true, 
            success: function (result) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
                alert(ajaxOptions);

            },
            complete: function () {

            }
        });
    }

    function updateonsuccess(id) {
    }


    function updateonfailure(id) {
    }

    function updateoncomplete(id) {
    }
</script>
}


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Change?" style="display:none;">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        <div id="dialogText"></div>
    </p>
    <p> Are you sure to change?</p>
</div>


<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Review</th>
    </tr>
    @{

        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name))</td>
                <td>@(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location))</td>
                <td>
                    @if (item.ReviewStatus == "Review")
                    {
                        <div id="REVIEW_@item.Location">
                            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_partialReview", item);  }
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div id="REVIEW_@item.Location">
                            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_partialReviewed", item);  }
                        </div>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

3 partial views:

```
@*//_partialReview.cshtml*@
@model MvcAjaxApp.Models.Restaurant

@Ajax.ActionLink("Review", "UpdateReviewStatus"
                        , new { data = Json.Encode(Model) }
                        , new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            UpdateTargetId = "REVIEW_" + Model.Location,
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            HttpMethod = "Get",
                            OnBegin = "return updateonbegin('" + Model.Location + "')",
                            OnSuccess = "return updateonsuccess ()",
                            OnComplete = "return updateoncomplete()",
                            OnFailure = "return updateonfailure()"

                        })

@*//_partialReviewed.cshtml*@
@model MvcAjaxApp.Models.Restaurant

@Ajax.ActionLink("Reviewed", "UpdateReviewStatus"
                        , new { data = Json.Encode(Model) }
                        , new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            UpdateTargetId = "REVIEW_" + Model.Location,
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            HttpMethod = "Get",
                            OnBegin = "return updateonbegin('" + Model.Location + "')",
                            OnSuccess = "return updateonsuccess ()",
                            OnComplete = "return updateoncomplete()",
                            OnFailure = "return updateonfailure()"
                        })


@*//_Review.cshtml*@
@model MvcAjaxApp.Models.Restaurant

@if (@Model.ReviewStatus == "Review")
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_partialReview", Model);  
}
else
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_partialReviewed", Model);  
}
```

The controller:

```
public class SimpleController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Simple/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var v = new List<Restaurant>
        {
            new Restaurant()
            {
                Name = "Chapati",
                Location = "SanJose", 
                ReviewStatus = "Review"
            },
            new Restaurant()
            {
                Name = "Naan",
                Location = "Sunnyvale", 
                ReviewStatus = "Review"
            },
            new Restaurant()
            {
                Name = "Roti",
                Location = "Cupertino", 
                ReviewStatus = "Review"
            }
        };

        return View(v.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult IsUpdatedSinceLastLoad(string location)
    {
        if (location == "Sunnyvale")
        {
            return Json("Ask");                            
        }
        return Json("Change");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpdateReviewStatus(string data )
    {
        var restaurant = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Restaurant>(data);
        restaurant.ReviewStatus = restaurant.ReviewStatus == "Review" ? "Reviewed" : "Review";
        return PartialView("_Review", restaurant);
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess u will have to change your ajax call to sync by adding   async: "false" property to your ajax call

Comment: Thanks for your response. That does not work if you check the variable b with alert message before the return b.  I tried it, and should have mentioned.